# pg_rewind failing to sync second database

Tags: postgresql, failover, postgresql-11

I have a PostgreSQL cluster with following databases with user `myuser`:

1. database1
2. database2

I have set up a replication with one master (192.168.50.8) and one slave (192.168.50.9). I failover to the slave, and when I try to failback to the original master using `pg_rewind` for every database, `pg_rewind` succeeds for the first database but fails for the second database.

For database1, running the following command on(192.168.50.8) works:

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_rewind -D "data_dir_path_here" --source-server="port=pg_port_here user=myuser dbname=database1 host=192.168.50.9"
```

For database2, running the following command on (192.168.50.8) gives me an error:

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_rewind -D "data_dir_path_here" --source-server="port=pg_port_here user=myuser dbname=database2 host=192.168.50.9"
```

Error:

```
target server must be shut down cleanly
failure, exiting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `pg_rewind` with the old master (192.168.50.8) to turn it into a slave. If the shutdown wan't clean, you have to run crash recovery on PostgreSQL (just start the server and stop it again as soon as crash recovery is done). Then you can run `pg_rewind`.

`pg_rewind` affects the whole database cluster, so you do *not* run it for each database. You run it once on the old master that is supposed to become the new slave.

If you use the `--source-server` option of `pg_rewind` to connect to the new master, it doesn't matter which database you specify. Any database will do, and the effect will be the same.

Comment: I am running pg_rewind on old master (192.168.50.8) only.

Comment: Yes, that's cool. Run it only there. If you cannot let the node perform crash recovery so that `pg_rewind` can run, you have to rebuild the new standby from scratch. `pg_rewind` is not guaranteed to succeed, it is just a quick way to rebuild a standby if possible.

Comment: Please note that we have multiple databases in our cluster. It works for first database but gives error for second database. I have searched on internet and all the example that i got are having only one database in cluster. My question is related to more than one database.

Comment: I think I finally understood you. I have updated the answer.

Comment: So that means i can't use pg_rewind? I can't club my databases into one. If i don't provide database name, it fails with error
```database 'myuser' does not exists```

Comment: No, no! As I said, you run it once **per cluster**. It will rewind **all databases in the cluster**.

Comment: Yes that i understood. But the problem is, when i run `pg_rewind` without specifying database name, like below:

`/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_rewind -D "data_dir_path_here" --source-server="port=pg_port_here user=myuser host=192.168.50.9"`

I get error:
`database 'myuser' does not exists`

Comment: Aah, get you. It doesn't matter which database you specify. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: That means even if i specify any database, pg_rewind will sync all the cluster instead of only that database. Is that correct ? If so, then i am good. But i haven't found this anywhere on postgresql documentation.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It will affect the whole cluster. Specifying the database is just a technicality for establishing a database connection.

Comment: ohh man. I thought it will sync that database when we specify the name. I am not sure why postgresql is missing such an important aspect from their documentation. Anyways, thanks a lot buddy. I just verified it and works like a charm.